# Error while trying to instantiate in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parent-child, instantiation

Today I encountered an error while programming in unity. The error is the following:

> Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a Prefab Asset is disabled to prevent data corruption

I discovered that the cause for this error is attempting to parent using a prefab. Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem.

I am trying to instantiate a GameObject and parent it to another object in the scene.

```
GameObject drawnCard = Instantiate(Card1, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
drawnCard.transform.SetParent(CardDesk.transform, false);
```

I define the Objects like so and assign them in the editor.

```
public GameObject Card1;
public GameObject Card2;
public GameObject CardDesk;
```

This means that I need to assign it in the prefab. BUT to assign a GameObject onto a script on a prefab it has to be a prefab itself. This is where I run into my problem, I can't not assign it to the prefab but to only the script in the scene because that returns an error since the prefab has an open field.

If I fill this field with my prefab I continue to attempt to parent a prefab in my script.

PS: first post here so I might have been unclear. Feel free to ask for clarification

Comment: Make your gameobject a prefab for instantiate, or simply make new gameobject how your currently doing.

Comment: I think you already answered yourself: You somehow need to find a way to get the reference to `CardDesk` on runtime .. a reference of an object existing in the scene, not a prefab